# Incoming packets drops when a lot of packets

Tags: router, gaming, lag, packet-loss

I encountered a problem with my network. When I play online games that send many packets, my ts3 connection statistics show 25% - 50% packet loss.

First game I noticed to do so is Space Engineers, when someone starts to dig and lots of chunks of asteroids spawn it makes my ts3 to lag.

Second game is GTA Online on PC, I can handle only sessions with 8 or less players, 14 players sessions lags my ts3, when there is 30 players my ts 3 connection drops, and reconnecting again every second, and I can't kill NPC/Players - when I shot to them they stand still, and die about 5 seconds later.

The last one is my own game, when I setup server to not pack packets into greater packages it sends 350 packets. but I receive only ~100, my ts3 lags. This scenario is easy to recreate for me. I know that game itself is not an issue because my friend is receiving all ~350 packets, and his ts3 connection doesn't report any incoming packet loss.

I have already checked - When I'm on another PC, connected to the same network (LAN cable) - I have same issue. So this probably eliminates my PC, so it may be my Router or ISP?

Before checking with another PC I was messing around with my LAN adapter settings but there was no difference so now it is set to its defaults.

I also checked my ping during this high packet loss, and my ping is still untouched, without online game running my ping is 24ms and with game running is 24ms too. My friends hear me normally it's the only packet I receive.

There is not much settings on router itself. I can share them with you but I don't really see what could be changed there, all settings seems to be my ISP related and they're probably shouldn't be changed. Settings like RFC 2364 PPaA encapsulation, VC multiplexing, QoS type UBR, Virtual circut 0 VPI 35 VCI, ADSL2+ Modulation and AUTO MTU size. My router is Linksys WAG200G, it is old one.

My internet connection is 1280Kb/s down and 128Kb/s up. But it's not an issue, because when games cause lags/drops of packets on TS, I still can watch streams with no lag.

Any thoughts how to fix that incoming packets bottleneck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made some further research, I used server-application to send n packets per second, and client-application to receive them. It turned out my connection can pass through only 150 packets per second, those are 1b packets. Then I switched, I run server on my end and was sending packets to remote client, my output packets rate was fine with 1000+ (which is maximum for my app).
I also ask friends to test their incoming packet rate, and they're receiving 1000+ packets per second. So what I did next was borrowing a router to check if mine is faulty. I already knew that packet throughput on LAN was ok, so only thing that could be broken at this point was ADSL modem in my router, or something on my ISP end. The borrowed router worked fine, so it turned out to be ADSL modem in my router what is broken. Already ordered new one.

Comment: When the uplink congests it should hold frames in memory until transmission, sounds like it was buffering nothing and just dropping. Good troubleshooting.